# Enzyme - How to access set input value in test file?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I am creating a unit test case via enzyme. in "register.js" file I made form states in the user object, But"register-test.js" file this state's value is given to me "undefined" : -

```
Expected: "dinesh"
Received: undefined
```

In register.js file  in user object states are set

```
this.state = {
            user: {
                firstName: ''  
            },
```

I am trying in "register-test.js".

```
describe('check first name', () => {  
  it('Check first name', () => {
   const wrapper = shallow(<RegisterPage />);
   wrapper.find('input[type="text"]').simulate('change', {target: {name: 'firstName', value: 'dinesh'}});
   expect(wrapper.state('firstName')).toEqual('dinesh');   
  })
})
```

Comment: Try `expect(wrapper.state('user.firstName')).toEqual('dinesh');`. Since `firstName` is defined within the `user` object.

Comment: This is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wrapper.find('input[type="text"]').simulate('change', {target: {name: 'firstName', value: 'dinesh'}});


expect(wrapper.state().user.firstName).toEqual('dinesh');
```

your firstName is under user

Comment: "Monzoor Tamal" Thank you very much.